# Create Flask POST request based on GET request

Tags: flask

I'm trying to integrate new auth lib to existing system using Flask, but project frontend sends GET request with search params, however authentication library accepts only POST request object with content-type `multipart/form-data`. So, I need a way to convert GET request into POST and pass to authenticaion library